# How to pass value of multiple input form in jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple input form. Once I put value and I should able to pass it through jQuery Ajax. It's working on simple html form. But in terms of multi-dimension form I fail.

Please help me get value in jQuery.

I have html form

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<?php
     for($a=0; $a<5; $a++) {
         echo "<input type='text' name='IdentityID[]' placeholder='GB' onchange=\"getdetail(IdentityID[id]); return false;\"/>";
     }
?>
</form>
```

JQuery ajax

```
function getdetail(IdentityID) {

     alert(IdentityID); //I wan the value to appear here

     $.ajax ({
             type: "POST",
             url: "getdetail.php",
             data: { IdentityID: IdentityID},
             success: function(data) {
                     $("#detail").html(data);
             }
     });
     return false;
}
```

> ReferenceError: IdentityID is not defined

Comment: Where is `id` at `onchange=\"getdetail(IdentityID[id])` defined?

Comment: Even if I used ***getdetail(IdentityID[$a])*** I get console ***ReferenceError: IdentityID is not defined***

Comment: Try substituting `this.value` for `IdentityID[id]`

Comment: Perfect. Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `this.value` for `IdentityID[id]` at `onchange=\"getdetail(IdentityID[id])`

Answer (score 0):

Serialise whole of the form using;

```
var dataVal = $('form').serializeArray();
```

and then you ajax request becomes:

```
$.ajax ({
             type: "POST",
             url: "getdetail.php",
             data: dataVal,
             success: function(data) {
                     $("#detail").html(data);
             }
     });
```

Comment: There must be straight way to do this. Passing IdentityID once I move cursor from input field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onchange="getdetail(this.value)"/>
```

That is the answer. Thanks to @guest271314